# How to use multiples DB's connections in a model with Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database, sequelize.js

I would like to make multiples connections in my DB but using the same model to any connection.

I tried to make a list of config connections using singleton pattern but I don't know how to proceed with that config connections

Database Client Object

```
class DatabaseClient {
    constructor(username, password, database) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.database = database;
        this.host = '127.0.0.1';
        this.dialect = 'mysql';

        this.logging = (log) => {
            console.log(log)
        }
    }
}
```

Databases connected with my application

```
class DatabasesConnected {
    constructor() {
        this.databases = []
    }

    addDatabase(loginUser, databaseClient) {
        this.databases.push({ loginUser, databaseClient })
        console.log(this.databases);
    }

    getDatabaseByLoginUser(loginUser) {
        const database = this.databases
            .filter(f => f.loginUser === loginUser)[0].databaseClient

        return database;
    }

    getDatabase() {
        return this.databases;
    }

}

module.exports = new DatabasesConnected()
```

I would like when the user logs in, I can use the connection config that was saved in DatabasesConnected, but I don't know how to make these multiple connections using just one model.

Comment: why would you want to create a new connection per user?

Comment: Also, filter returns an array and the code is wrong, the key of array will throw error. Probably rewrite with find() and a null check

Comment: const database = this.databases.find(f => f.loginUser === loginUser);
if(database){return database.databaseClient;}

Comment: I guess this is gonna help you https://medium.com/unetiq/using-multiple-databases-with-nodejs-and-sequelize-59e0abcbbe6f

Comment: Dhananjai Pa, Each client in the system must have a different DB since it can't be shared between different users, so I can't use a database for the whole application, thank you so much I saw now that filter error

Comment: Guilherme Martin, In this case there is a DB for a specific model (1: 1), I need to have several connections for a specific model (n: 1)

Comment: `Each client in the system must have a different DB since it can't be shared between different users` Can you elaborate on this? One DB for tons of user is pretty standard; why wouldn't that work for your app? And are we talking about multiple DBs oder just multiple connections?

Comment: @ChrisG , There is a DB with the security context of the application where will have the users, access rules, connection string for the DB, this would be just the security context of the application.

The other context would be the customer information itself, this information cannot blend with information from other application customers, as it involves data that cannot be shared between other customers, business data from each company that must be confidential, for example. This is what I need in this context I have a different connection to each model to perform actions in DB.